# 'Suggest helping' vs 'Offer to help' - in reported speech

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

My English exercise book has a question related to reported speech like this:

> Choose the sentence which is closest in meaning to be printed one
>
> **“Shall I help you with the washing-up, Jane?” John said.**
> A. John told Jane to help him with the washing-up.
> B. John asked if Jane should help him with the washing-up.
> C. John suggested helping Jane with the washing-up.
> D. John offered to help Jane with the washing-up.

Even though the given answer key is D, I still think C can be another choice. If you don't think so, could you kindly explain what makes D is the only choice in this case?

Comment: Did you find a dictionary definition of *suggest* that would fit the intent of the key sentence? You should add that info. to your question.

Comment: C is awkward. He suggested helping Jane, to whom?

Comment: I agree with @DamkerngT. Answer C does a good job of capturing the meaning of the original quote, but it's not written in good English. It should say something like, "John suggested _that he could help_ Jane with the washing-up."

Comment: Really they're all awkward. "The washing-up" sounds strange to me.

Comment: C could also be interpreted as "John suggested that James helped Jane with ..."

Comment: @DJM - It might be a regionalism; it's found in plenty of books. Here's one: _"Anyway,” said Selina, “we could have got her to help with the washing-up. There's an awful stack of it tonight."_ The author (Xavier Herbert) is Australian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C. John suggested helping Jane with the washing-up.

Consider some contexts in which this sentence might occur.

> Julie asked John what she could do to speed things up. John suggested helping Jane with the washing-up.
>
> Jane pointed out that Julie was old enough now to have some regular chores, and asked John if he had any ideas. John suggested helping Jane with the washing-up.

*suggest VERBing* does not imply that *VERB* has any particular subject; specifically, it does not imply that the subject suggests that ***he*** should *VERB*. Consequently, this sentence does not, as the quotation does, imply that John made an offer to help; it at most puts *helping Jane* forward as a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of those English niggles in that it comes down to a distinction between "shall" and "should".

"Shall" is a modal auxiliary verb, the first-person version of "will", and indicates the future tense.  Frankly, I see your point in wondering about the validity of C, because *shall* is used as a suggestion in other contexts, but this is an offer to help, and not him suggesting it as an exciting night out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

"

> C is awkward. He suggested helping Jane, to whom? –  Damkerng T. 4 hours ago
>
> I agree with @DamkerngT. Answer C does a good job of capturing the meaning of> >the original quote, but it's not written in good English. It should say >something like, "John suggested that he could help Jane with the washing-up." –  >J.R.♦ 4 hours ago"

Actually, it's perfectly correct English, although the use of the past tense verb with a present participle is less common in modern use; also, there need not be a person to whom he needs to suggest anything - sentences do not require an object, only a subject.

> suggest VERBing does not imply any particular subject to VERB; it merely puts >VERBing forward as a good idea. Consequently, this sentence does not, as the >quotation does, imply that John made an offer to help.

It doesn't *need* to imply anything, because it states it pretty explicitly in that sentence, by using the pronoun, "Jane".

He VERBED Jane.  *ahem*  Not what I meant.  And you don't "verb" a subject, anyway, subjects verb *objects*, but - as mentioned above - you don't need to explicitly state the object - a sentence need only have a subject and a finite verb in order to be complete.

Importantly, "helping" isn't the finite verb in that sentence - "suggested" is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Do you imply that the choice C & D have the same meaning in this context?

Comment: I see that I confused you by my slovenly editing - I've corrected "imply to VERB" to "imply that VERB has a particular subject" and added some examples to clarify my meaning.

Comment: Neither of videoartifex's answers is even slightly useful. Stick with StoneyB. He's not being very concise this time, but he knows his stuff.